# Pull Every Quarter that a project is active

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I have a list of projects that have various start and end dates.
As an example, some projects might only last one quarter where others might last 3 quarters and may cross calendar years.

I want something that would pull 1 value for each quarter if it is active and would hope to have a measure show a count of 1 for each project where a project is active.

What is the easiest way to do this? Thanks

Comment: What's the format of your list of projects?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.